# AngularJS Web service asmx $http post

Tags: angularjs, web-services

I am trying to send some form variables to a web service. The web service is suppose to return JSON which I want to populate as grid. My service is fine and I have already tested it.

My Controller looks like this

```
var postUrl = 'schedule.asmx/getSchedulerGrid';
$scope.getSchedulerGrid = function() {
    $http.post(postUrl, {
        type: $scope.selectedType,
        branchId: $scope.selectedBranch
    }).success(function(responseData) {
        var myjson = JSON.parse(responseData);
        $scope.scheduleGrid = myjson;
        console.log($scope.selectedType);
        console.log($scope.selectedBranch);
    });
}
```

`$scope.selectedType` and `$scope.selectedBranch` are getting values assigned correctly.

However, when I run the program i.e. fill the type, branch and click on Go which has `ng-click`, I am getting error like this

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter: type.

at System.Web.Services.Protocols.  ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read (HttpRequest request)
```

My web.config has

```
<add name="HttpGet"/>
<add name="HttpPost"/>
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

My webservice is something like this

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getSchedulerGrid(int type, string branchId)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Context.Response.Clear();
    Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    .....
}
```

Comment: So what happens if you remove the parameters? what happens if you only leave the string parameter?

Comment: Nothing. While debugging, its not even hitting the web service. Has it got to do with the way I have defined the $http post data? Thanks

Comment: Check the chrome console or firefox firebug and see if the request is being made and if it has the right parameters in it. I don't think there's a problem with $http but rather with the webservice

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to uncomment the line [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] in the web service.